# Package tikz Error: I do not know the path named ... No such error in earlier versions of TeXLive!

Tags: tikz-pgf, scoping

I drew the following using TeXlive 2018 and it was fine. In TeXlive 2020 it was fine also. But now  using TeXlive 2022 it returned the following error! I know the problem is `scope` part! without `scope` it has no error.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{through,calc,decorations.markings,positioning,angles}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{scope}[shift={(-0.6,0.05)}]
        \path[name path= C] (-2.1,-0.8) .. controls (-1.9,-0.35) and (-1.6,0.64) .. (-0.8,0.65) .. controls (0.1,0.65) and (0.45,-1) .. (1.1,-1) .. controls (1.75,-1) and (2.4,0.25) .. (2.6,0.7);%2
    \end{scope}
    
    \draw[name path= Cp]  (-3.35,-0.5) .. controls (-1.9,0) and (1.3,0.1) .. (2.7,-0.4);
    \draw[thick, white](-2.488,-0.283) .. controls (-1.89,-0.16) and (-1,-0.09) .. (-0.38,-0.08);
    \fill[name intersections={of =C and Cp, by={p, q, z} },draw] (p) node[fill,circle, inner sep=1pt ]{} node[below]{$p$}  (q)  node[fill,circle, inner sep=1pt ]{} node[below]{$q$};
    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\path[name path  global= C]`, see the tikz documentation.

Comment: The error turned to another error: `Package pgf Error: No shape named intersection-1 is known. ...ctions={of =C and Cp, by={p, q, z} },draw]`

Comment: compiles fine for me in a current texlive.

Comment: using TeXlive 2022 and TeXstudio 4.3.1?

Comment: For me too compiles fine after applying Ulrike's suggestion.

Comment: That is weird a little!`texworks` also returned same error: l.15 ...ctions={of =C and Cp, by={p, q, z} },draw]
                                                   (p) node[fill,circle, inn...

? 

! Package pgf Error: No shape named `intersection-2' is known.

Comment: sorry. Sorry. sorry. that was my fault.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, it seems that the semantic changed between TL2018 and 2022... so probably this question is worth an answer, so that it's stored for posterity...